# JavaScript new Promise shorthand

Tags: javascript, function, promise, es6-promise

I'm wondering if there's any shorthand to create a promise in JavaScript, or any way to add .then to a normal function. Example:

```
dbl = a => a | 0 ? a * 2 : !1;
dbl(10).then(r => r / 2); // should be original number entered.
```

I want to either make the dbl function instead be a promise, but stay fairly short. Or to add some sort of protoype to function that would let me do something like the above code.

Comment: `Promise.resolve` perhaps?

Comment: @JaromandaX Hmm, that might work. How would I use it?

Comment: Promises are for async operations, why do you wan't to do this?!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to do this, but you can wrap any value in a promise by writing `Promise.resolve(value)`. You can attach `then` callbacks to the resulting promise.

```
dbl = a => a|0 ? a*2 : !1
Promise.resolve(dbl(10)).then(r => r/2) //should be original number entered.
```

Comment: Thanks. This isn't probably something I'll use frequently but I was really just wondering if it's possible.